# timestamp is inserted as null when I convert it from string

Tags: hive

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
ctn string
, platform_code string
, status string
, status_date date
)
PARTITIONED BY(time_key string)
STORED AS ORC;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
time_key timestamp
, ctn string
, platform_code string
, status string
, status_date timestamp
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

In table1 one I have some data. Example

```
(9056697563,C,,,2017-09-22)
```

`status` is empty string and `status_date` is `null`. I need to insert this row while converting 2017-09-22 to timestamp. When I try this

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time_key, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS time_key
, ctn
, platform_code
, status
, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time_key, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS status_date
FROM table1
WHERE time_key = '2017-09-22';
```

both `time_key` and `status_date` have value `2017-09-22 00:00:00`, but when I try

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time_key, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS time_key
, ctn
, platform_code
, status
, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time_key, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS status_date
FROM table1
WHERE time_key = '2017-09-22';
```

`time_key` ends as `null` and `status_date` as `2017-09-22 00:00:00`

Why does this happen?

EDIT

After I removed `AS time_key` and `AS status_date` it worked properly. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Use the DATE type

Comment: If Hive can't convert the data in the column to the desired data type, it simply returns null.